# Why is Uncrustify forcing a space before my Objective-C block closing brace?

Tags: objective-c, xcode5, indentation, uncrustify

I'm having problems with my -rather extense- [Uncrustify Configuration](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Goles/e16474d59b2c03d6453c/raw/5b36f3494bc168b9a9220cd346129a54228748aa/uncrustify.cfg). I'm using Xcode to auto-run Uncrustify.

For some reason, Uncrustify seems to add a Space before the closing Brace of a block declaration.

**Sample Input**

```
 [_collectionView performBatchUpdates:nil completion:^(BOOL finished) {
 }];
```

**Sample Output** (note the `forced` space before the closing Brace)

```
 [_collectionView performBatchUpdates:nil completion:^(BOOL finished) {
  }];
```

**Desired Output**

```
 [_collectionView performBatchUpdates:nil completion:^(BOOL finished) {
 }];
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I did find a solution for this.

I ended up using the following parameter in my `uncrustify.cfg`

`indent_oc_block_msg_xcode_style = true`

Got this tip by asking in the Source Forge project website (after a week or so).

Comment: Can you link to where you asked this on the Source Force site? I can't seem to get it to work in my uncrustify.cfg